# How to optimize my anagram search function?

Tags: python, optimization, anagram

I'm working on a problem from HackerRank - I have a working anagram search function, however, it is too slow when it comes to large input arrays/strings.

The `dictionary` and `query` inputs are both lists of words, the function should look for the number of anagrams for each word in `query` and return a list of anagram counts corresponding to each word.

```
dictionary = ["abc", "bca"]
query = ["abc", "xyz"]

# return [2, 0]
```

I have tried 2 approaches to reduce the run time but with no success (the max. time allowed limit is 10 seconds for the hidden tests) -

1. to break out of loops as soon as I know there will not be any more matches
2. to create a sub dictionary of only the words with equal length of the search word

```
def stringAnagram(dictionary, query):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(dictionary)):
            dictionary[i] = "".join(sorted(dictionary[i]))
    dictionary.sort()
    dictionary.sort(key=len)
    
    for word in query:
        i = 0
        sortedWord = "".join(sorted(word))
        subDictionary = [entry for entry in dictionary if len(entry) == len(sortedWord)]
        
        for entry in subDictionary:
            if sortedWord == entry:
                i += 1
        result.append(i)
        
    return result
```

Can anyone point out where the bottleneck is?

Comment: You never actually gave a clear problem statement of what `stringAnagram` is supposed to do, some example inputs and outputs would help.

Comment: In the future, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate for this since your code is working already. Of course you'd want to reformat the question to match the rules of that site.

Comment: @CoryKramer Sorry, I forgot to add that, I added an explanation and an example now

Comment: collections.Counter is your friend.  That's what I used when I wrote https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/anagrams/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating permutations of a string of particular length and comparing it to see if there is any match, there is a simple observation, and that is the number of any character would be the same in both strings if they are anagram.

Answer (score 0):

```
def stringAnagram(dictionary, query):
    sorted_dictionary = {''.join(sorted(word)) for word in words}
    result = [word for word in query if ''.join(sorted(word)) in sorted_dictionary]
    return result
```

Comment: This would only return a list of words that have anagrams in the dictionary - is it possible to add a count for how many anagrams are there for each word in the dictionary?